# Can you create Excel hyperlinks to specific values/words within cells?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, row, formula, cell

I'm creating a large spreadsheet for my job and need to create an Index at the top which links to specific sections of the workbook. I know how to link to cells within a spreadsheet - however, this spreadsheet will be consistently adding and removing rows, meaning the cell numbers will be changing.

Is there a way to create a hyperlink to a specific value/word within a cell? For instance, can I create a link to a cell with the header phrase "Transactions List," that will always link their even if its cell number changes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is way. You can use `Match()` function within `Hyperlink()` function to refer cell dynamically. Lets demonstrate how to do. Suppose you have `Transactions List` (see attached screenshot below) word in `Column F` and you want to hyperlink that cell even when you add few rows before that cell. Match function will find row number of cell containing `Transactions List` in specified column and link to that cell by below formula.

```
=HYPERLINK("#F"&MATCH("Transactions List",F:F,0),"Hello Hyperlink")
```

Even you can hyperlink cell in another sheet by following formula. Change sheet name in your case.

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!F"&MATCH("Transactions List",Sheet2!F:F,0),"Hello Hyperlink")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is super helpful! I got the link to work - the only thing is I can't get it to display any text other than "0." The formula I'm currently using is:

=HYPERLINK("#A"&MATCH("TRANSACTIONS LIST",A:A,0),"TRANSACTIONS LIST")

Essentially I'm trying to have a link reading reading "Transactions List" that leads to a heading several rows down called "Transactions List." Am I inputting something wrong?

Comment: Couldn't understand your query?